# Mostrar una salida en un orden determinado en linux

Tags: script

Hola necesito hacer un script que coja el archivo de /etc/group y muestre primero el guid y despues el nombre de cada grupo por ejemplo:
1:root, con esto less /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 1,3 | sort  me muestra de la siguiente:

[image: ejecucion del comando]

gracias

un saludo

Comment: Puedes usar `awk -F: '{print $3,$1}' /etc/group | sort -n`.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` preserva el orden de los elementos que encuentra en cada línea.

Debieras probar `aws` en vez de `cut`:

```
cat /etc/group | awk -v OFS=":" -F":" '{ print $3 ":" $1}' | sort
```